# What is the reason for this weird behaviour of `import * as A` and `import A`?

Tags: ecmascript-6, commonjs

As the following code shows, why doesn't the import Parent from 'Parent1.js work? Why does snippet2 import A correctly, but snippet1 doesn't?

In my understanding, exports should be equal to module.exports, so snippet1 should work...

snippet1:

```
// Parent1.js
    var a = exports.a = 1;

//index.js
    import Parent from 'Parent1.js' // Not working
    import * as Parent from 'Parent1.js' // Worked!
```

snippets2:

```
// Parent1.js
    module.exports = {a:1}

//index.js
    import Parent from 'Parent1.js' // Worked
```

Comment: What do you mean by "worked" and "not work"? What error messages or unexpected behavior did you observe?

Comment: @skrrgwasme meaning whether calling `Parent.a` pops Parent is undefined error

Comment: They are the same unless you have circular dependencies. The problem must be in the way you tested it.

Answer (score 0):

You're using ES6 syntax with `import` statements here.  In `snippet1` for `import Parent from 'Parent1.js'` to work you need to use `export default a`.  This will make whatever `a` is the only thing that gets exported from `Parent1.js`.  Furthermore, whenever you invoke `Parent` in `snippet1` you will get the results for `a`.

By doing `import * as Parent from Parent1.js` you are collecting anything that might have been exported into a collection and naming it `Parent`.  To access `a` you call it as `Parent.a`.  Here `Parent` refers to the collection whereas above `Parent` is an alias for `a`.